# ebay json api testing tool not finding sku in calls

Tags: c#, json, api, soap, ebay-api

I'm playing around with the sandbox api for ebay, but I keep running into errors.
So you can use the API test [tool here](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx?index=0&api=inventory&call=inventory_item-sku__GET&variation=json).

Now I have products which are on the sand box my ebay active listings page.
But when I use the API testing tool and try to use this call `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/{SKU}` it gives the following error in response body

`{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 25710,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "We didn't find the entity you are requesting. Please verify the request"
    }
  ]
}`

Now I have done some reading and they say as long as I use the inventory tracking method `item.InventoryTrackingMethod = InventoryTrackingMethodCodeType.SKU;` set to SKU it should work. So I'm not sure why it's not.

There are 3 potential problems I thought might be causing it.

1. The sandbox API has problems and is buggy(unlikely but possible)
2. It's something to do with country, but I'm not sure it's this either.
3. Because I'm adding products using the fixedpriceitem call using SOAP API it's not matching with the JSON API

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for anyone else who might run into this issue, it seems like the SOAP API and the Inventory API are incompatible.

I have no way to confirm this exactly but Inventory API JSON calls are correct, but they are returning test products with the SKU I specified in the SOAP API call.

If anyone else can provide input to confirm this problem or outline exactly what's going on that would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer but might get you in right direction.

I'll try to explain how I'm retrieving SKUs (but when using SOAP).

When I'm fetching Active/SoldList items via GetMyEbaySelling call. 
The main identifier taking precedence of Item is always Item.ItemID (if present).

Are you using multivariation listing?
Have you tried passing ItemID as a main identifier and then finding right SKU for the given variation under your ItemID?

`For multiple-variation listings, a SKU value is actually required for each product variation within the listing. However, the SKU value for each product variation is actually specified at the variation level (Item.Variations.Variation.SKU) field, and the Item.SKU) field should not be included in the call request.`

Comment: Hi @karol Flis thanks for helping, yeah I'm not having issues with using the SOAP API, but I want to use the JSON API and this is where I'm running into the issues. The JSON API doesn't use the ItemID field at all in the request. [Here is the docs page](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/bulkUpdatePriceQuantity)